# Is this the most efficient way to create a BuffreredImage from image data in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am revisiting some old code, this downloads an image from a URL then creates a `BufferedImage` using a reader. Because my application is now downloading more images this code is becoming more significant.  Can this be done in a more efficent way?

```java
public static byte[] convertUrlToByteArray(URL url) throws IOException
{
    //Get imagedata, we want to ensure we just write the data as is as long as in a supported format
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(URL_TIMEOUT);
    connection.setReadTimeout(URL_TIMEOUT);

    //Do this because some services like Discogs reject calls if not from known user-agent, we pretend we are using
    //firefox,
    //TODO perhaps should be more sophisticated and select from a random list of browser user agents
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");

    // Since you get a URLConnection, use it to get the InputStream
    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    // Now that the InputStream is open, get the content length
    int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
    // To avoid having to resize the array over and over and over as
    // bytes are written to the array, provide an accurate estimate of
    // the ultimate size of the byte array
    ByteArrayOutputStream tmpOut;
    if (contentLength != -1)
    {
        tmpOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(contentLength);
    }
    else
    {
        tmpOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(16384); // Pick some appropriate size
    }

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    while (true)
    {
        int len = in.read(buf);
        if (len == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        tmpOut.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    tmpOut.close(); // No effect, but good to do anyway to keep the metaphor alive
    return tmpOut.toByteArray();
}

public static BufferedImage createBufferedImageFromRawData(byte[] imageData, String logDescriptor)
{
    if (imageData.length > MAX_IMAGE_SIZE)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage").severe("ImageSizeTooLargeToProcess:"+logDescriptor);
        return null;
    }

    BufferedImage bi = null;
    ImageInputStream stream = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
    try
    {
        ImageReader ir;
        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
        stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(bais);
        Iterator<ImageReader> i = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);

        //Try each reader until we get one that could create an Image
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            ir = i.next();
            bi = createBufferedImageUsingReader(stream, logDescriptor, ir);
            if (bi != null)
            {
                break;
            }

            //Close the old Stream
            try
            {
                stream.close();
                bais.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Recreate stream to avoid flushing problem
            bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
            stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(bais);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage").log(Level.SEVERE,"IOException reading image:"+logDescriptor+":"+ex.getMessage(),ex);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError ome)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage").log(Level.SEVERE,"OutOfMemoryException reading image:"+logDescriptor+":"+ome.getMessage(),ome);
        System.runFinalization();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException re)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage").log(Level.SEVERE,"RuntimeException reading image:"+logDescriptor, re);
    }
    catch(Exception exe)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage").log(Level.SEVERE,"Exception reading image:"+logDescriptor+":"+exe.getMessage(),exe);
        System.runFinalization();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            stream.close();
            bais.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return bi;
}

public static BufferedImage createBufferedImageUsingReader(ImageInputStream stream, String logDescriptor, ImageReader ir)
{
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    try
    {
        ir.setInput(stream);
        ImageReadParam param = ir.getDefaultReadParam();

        Iterator<ImageTypeSpecifier> it;

        // Synchronized because ImageReader seems to come from a singleton and the call to ir.getImageTypes()
        // can throw ConcurrentModificationException because could have two threads both accessing the same image readers
        // image types
        synchronized(CoverImage.class)
        {
            it = ir.getImageTypes(0);
        }
        //Used to loop round all ImageTypeSpecifier but to set Color Space as RGB
        //But set destination type to RGB this only works before Java 6 build 15
        //if the first colour space is RGB, it fails if have gray space image which supports both colour and gray
        //But has gray as the first colour space.
        //So for now only check the first one as this seems to be the one that gets used.
        if (it.hasNext())
        {
            ImageTypeSpecifier type = it.next();
            ColorSpace cs = type.getColorModel().getColorSpace();

            if (cs.isCS_sRGB())
            {
                param.setDestinationType(type);
            }
        }
        bi = ir.read(0, param);
        ir.dispose();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage").log(Level.SEVERE,"IOException reading image:"+logDescriptor,ex);

    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException iae)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage").log(Level.SEVERE,"IllegalArgumentException reading image:"+logDescriptor, iae);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError ome)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage").log(Level.SEVERE,"OutOfMemoryException reading image:"+logDescriptor+":"+ome.getMessage(),ome);
        System.runFinalization();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException re)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage").log(Level.SEVERE,"RuntimeException reading image:"+logDescriptor, re);
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage").log(Level.SEVERE,"Exception reading image:"+logDescriptor, exe);
    }
    finally
    {
        //See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6687968 & https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4797189
        //TODO RunFinalization has to create a thread, massively increasing thread count so although the above SUN
        //bugs are still open we don't really want to call this every time we create a BufferedImage from Reader
        System.runFinalization();
    }
    return bi;
}
```

Comment: not sure if your method will be more efficient for a single image, but you should at least think also about loading multiple images in parallel - it's pretty simple in Java

Comment: true, my app is multithreaded but this part is not so I should at least do that

Comment: What in particular are you doing with the `BufferedImage`?

Comment: That's a lot of code, most of which is likely not relevant for the question. Broadly speaking, there are two steps: 1. Reading the data and 2. creating the BufferedImage. I'm pretty sure that the first one will always be the bottleneck, so why bother about the `BufferedImage` part? Beyond that, why are you not just using `ImageIO.read(..., inputData)` (where `inputData` is either the original URL input stream, or a `ByteArrayInputStream` of the data that was read)?

Comment: Actually BufferdImage creation also takes some cpu resource but I dont know why im not using ImageIO.read() I think there was some issues reading some times of images and so I then started iterating around readers but maybe no longer neccessary.

Comment: I would definitely pass the URL directly to [ImageIO.read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29).  If that fails with a particular image, please ask a new question Stack Overflow about it;  I would be interested in seeing any such images.

Comment: @Marco13 I remember the issue now, if I use the direct ImageIO.url then I dont have the access to the original bytes so when I go to save the image to db I get only the version created by ImageIo rather than the original image

Comment: I see. Then you could still read the image data into a `byte array[]` in one step (then save it to the DB), and then decode this data using `ImageIO.read( ... new ByteArrayInputStream(array))`.

Comment: True, I will try it out

Comment: Multithreading made quite a difference, using ImageIO.read( ... new ByteArrayInputStream(array)) didn't , however gave no errors either and i alwasy prefer simpler code if possible so will migrate to  just use that.

Comment: I'm quite confident you don't need the synchronization part (and if you did, synchronizing on your class wouldn't work if other code didn't). Also, creating an `ImageInputStream` from a `ByteArrayInputStream` will create temp file for caching by default (same when using `ImageIO.read(..)` as @Marco13 suggested). You can disable this by setting `ImageIO.setUseCache(false)`. Better yet, use a [`ByteArrayImageInputStream`](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-core/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/stream/ByteArrayImageInputStream.java) directly.